# Upper limit of instructions of a program for a Turing machine that has been converted from a real programming language

Tags: turing-machines, c

Imagine that I have an algorithm written in C that is of, let's say, 10,000 characters in length. Such a program can be simulated on a turing machine (Wikipedia:
Anything a real computer can compute, a Turing machine can also compute. For example: "A Turing machine can simulate any type of subroutine found in programming languages, including recursive procedures and any of the known parameter-passing mechanisms"). Intuitively it seems obvious that there exists such a program among all programs for a Turing machine of at most $10^{10^{100}}$ (googolplex) instructions. How can I go about proving the last sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a Turing machine that implements a C interpreter, and is less than a googolplex instructions long.

Of course you probably wouldn't want to actually do that, as that would be far too tedious and painful.  So, for example, perhaps you instead might write a Turing machine that can evaluate any boolean circuit; then write a boolean circuit that implements a 8086 microprocessor, and hardcode it with the Turing machine; then write an assembler and C compiler for 8086, and hardcode it.  If all of that, plus the C program itself, fits in less than a googolplex instructions, then you have built up a way to implement your C program (very very slowly) using a Turing machine.

Comment: On GitHub or GitLab there are a number of projects that look like they do something like this.  Just to list the first one I saw: https://github.com/Meyermagic/Turing-Machine-Compiler